# WPF: When Adding items to a listview they become empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

Im a bit new to WPF and I cant seem to figure out why the items I add to a listview are displaying empty.

Here is my XAML

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource BillingIncrements}, Path=ID}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Bill Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource BillingIncrements}, Path=Description}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Here is the code

```
lstBillGroups.Items.Add(New StlReportPlugins.BillingIncrements With {.ID = 100, .Description = "Test"})
```

Here is the output 
(couldnt post a pic because i dont have enough points)

[Link to pic](http://i369.photobucket.com/albums/oo132/mrpyrochris/Listview.gif)
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your XAML should look like

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource BillingIncrements}}>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Bill Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you have a look at output window in VS while debugging your app you'll see a bunch of WPF binding errors, which helps a lot to spot mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was the answer. Also thanks for the tip